# commiting all files except two in git

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have a bulk of modified files.

I want to commit them in 3 commits.

(some added by auto-merge, some relevant for bug1, some relevant for bug2)

how can I commit only 2 files out of 30 ?

how can I commit 25 out of 30 ?

Comment: By specifying them? Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: For the two files, why not just commit by name. For 25, I have nothing good. Maybe commit all 30, then remove 5 (unless the 5 have a common extension or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, add all files:

```
git add .
```

To commit 2(or any less no.) files:

```
git commit -m "my commit msg" file1 file2
```

To commit 25:

```
git commit -m "my commit msg" file1 file2 .. file25
```

or

```
git reset HEAD file26 file27 ..
git commit -m "my commit msg"
```

Basically, first remove the files you don't want to commit from "Changes to be committed" list, then commit all remaining ones.

Comment: `git reset` doesn't remove my changes?

Comment: @EladBenda Nope, it unstages your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add only 2 files and commit!

```
$git add <file1>

$git add <file12>

$git commit -m "Your message"
```

If you permanently dont want to stage file(s), make a `.gitignore` file in you folder where you have initialised the git and specify the files that dont want to be tracked.